# How to deep map JavaScripts for (var a in b) to ClojureScript?

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

This code appears to treat an object as a set of key-value pairs:

```
for (var a in b) { ...
```

And I want to map it to ClojureScript

Now ordinarily I could just do:

```
(doseq [[k v] (js->clj js/b)]
```

The problem is that `b` contains a nested map - and `js-clj` is shallow.

The other problem is that the keys in the object are integers - so accessing the keys by field values won't work. ie

```
{0 #object... 1 #object ... }
```

My question is: **How to deep map JavaScripts `for (var a in b)` to ClojureScript?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(doc js->clj)

-------------------------
cljs.core/js->clj
([x] [x & opts])
  Recursively transforms JavaScript arrays into ClojureScript
  vectors, and JavaScript objects into ClojureScript maps.  With
  option ':keywordize-keys true' will convert object fields from
  strings to keywords.
```

As you can see `js-clj` transforms JS objects **recursively** into ClojureScript datastructures.

So when you have a JS object:

```
{1: {2: "a"}, 3: [true, 4]}
```

`js->clj` will convert it into following ClojureScript object:

```
{"1" {"2" "a"}, "3" [true 4]}
```

As far as I know when you iterate over JS object properties with `for` it will iterate over only properties of the object you are passing, it's not going down into those properties' properties:

```
for (a in {1: {2: "a"}, 3: {4: "b"}) { console.log(a); };
```

It will print only `1` and `3` and  won't go down into `2` or `4`.

So a ClojureScript version of that `for` loop would be:

```
(doseq [[k v] (js->clj js/g)]
  (.log js/console k))
```

So I am not clear why you have stated that `js->clj` is shallow when it isn't.

If you would like to walk over the whole datastructure recursively, than you could use `clojure.walk/prewalk` or `clojure.walk/postwolk` which will visit all your values in a datastructure (it knows how to go into maps, vectors, sets etc.) and call your function for each value it encounters:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk
  #(do (.log js/console "PostWalking" %)
       %)
  {:a 1 :b {:c 2}})

(clojure.walk/prewalk
  #(do (.log js/console "PreWalking" %)
       %)
  {:a 1 :b {:c 2}})
```